# getting the following error when using firestore Firestore: Error: FIRESTORE (8.1.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm currently working on an app and it was working fine for awhile...when I was signing up I add the users to firestore and it still worked but now whenever I use firestore in some other screen it keeps throwing the following error:

```
 @firebase/firestore:, Firestore (8.1.2): FIRESTORE (8.1.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state

Stack trace:
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
  node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
  http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:171277:27
```

and this is the code of the screen in which I'm getting errors

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons, FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { ListItem, Avatar, Badge } from 'react-native-elements';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import theme from '../Props/theme';

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      patients: [],
    };

    this.patient = null;
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.patient = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('Patients')
      .where('doctorEmail', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        var docData = snapshot.docs.map((document) => document.data());
        this.setState({
          patients: docData,
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FFF' }}>
        <StatusBar hidden />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 10, right: 20 }}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.push('Settings');
          }}>
          <Ionicons name="ios-settings-sharp" color="#02075d" size={40} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.patients}
          style={{ marginTop: 50 }}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem>
              <ListItem.Content
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
                  padding: 20,
                  borderRadius: 20,
                }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                  <View>
                    <Avatar
                      rounded
                      icon={{ name: 'user', type: 'font-awesome' }}
                      activeOpacity={0.7}
                      source={{
                        uri:
                          'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
                      }}
                    />
                    <Badge
                      status={
                        item.allVisitsCompleted === false
                          ? theme.darkPink
                          : theme.darkBlue
                      }
                      containerStyle={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: -1,
                        right: -3,
                      }}
                      badgeStyle={
                        item.allVisitsCompleted === false
                          ? {
                              width: 15,
                              height: 15,
                              borderRadius: 7.5,
                              backgroundColor: theme.darkPink,
                            }
                          : {
                              width: 15,
                              height: 15,
                              borderRadius: 7.5,
                              backgroundColor: theme.darkBlue,
                            }
                      }
                    />
                  </View>
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', marginLeft: 20 }}>
                    <ListItem.Title>{item.patientName}</ListItem.Title>
                    <ListItem.Subtitle>{item.patientId}</ListItem.Subtitle>
                  </View>

                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{ marginLeft: 185, marginTop: 5 }}
                    onPress={() =>
                      this.props.navigation.navigate('Edit', {
                        details: item,
                      })
                    }>
                    <FontAwesome name="edit" size={24} color="black" />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </ListItem.Content>
            </ListItem>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I personally think that this error is occurring because of the fetching function (onSnapshot or .get function)...If you have any idea how to fix this please let me know...Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue now...if anyone is facing this issue...do the following steps:

- Run `expo install firebase` in the root of your project
- If it still doesn't work import your config file (If you have it) in all the screens where you are getting the above error